# Array of multiple images

Tags: php, html, arrays, image

PHP:

```
$cards = array("Messi ", "Ronaldo ", "Ibrahimovic ", "Ribery ", "Robben ", "Neymar ", "Rooney ", "Casillas ", "Falcao ", "Van Persie ", "Hazard ");

    shuffle($cards);
    echo $cards[0]
```

I would like to make an array of images. The idea is that instead of echoing/printing text, it prints/echos an image from the array list, but how I would I do this? I made a array that randomizes the string chosen but I don't know where to start with displaying images via arrays. Please help! :)

Comment: What's preventing you from echoing an image tag with a random file name?

Comment: Where are your images and how did you named them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will take the array shuffle it  and then print an image for each player. Assuming every image is jpg.

```
$cards = array("Messi", "Ronaldo", "Ibrahimovic", "Ribery", "Robben", "Neymar", "Rooney", "Casillas", "Falcao", "Van Persie", "Hazard");

shuffle($cards);
foreach ($cards as $card) {
    echo "<img src='imagesDirectory/$card.jpg'> <br>";
}
```

in case you want to print only one card remove the foreach and write :

```
$card = $cards['0'];
echo "<img src='imagesDirectory/$card.jpg'> <br>";
```

in case you want to show a fixed number of cards :

```
$numberOfCards = 10; // this is the number of cards you want to show
for ($i=0; $i <= $numberOfCards ; $i++) { 
    $card = $cards[$i];
    echo "<img src='imagesDirectory/$card.jpg'> <br>";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Do you know how I would display 10 random cards?

Comment: @journey i edited my answer so you could see how to show 10 random cards